# ie 10 localStorage.getItem returns error: more data is available

Tags: local-storage, internet-explorer-10

I'm using the localStorage in my web application to save al kinds of data. However this does not seem to work with internet explorer 10.

When i try to test this with:

```
localStorage.testItem = "testing"
```

it works fine, however when I try

```
localStorage.setItem('testItem', 'testing');
```

I get an error: More data available. What is going on here?

Comment: I have a screenshot in front of me of the "More data is available." error, but in IE8.  I don't know the cause yet, but you're not alone!

Comment: The error I'm seeing is that IE8 and IE11 (absolute latest release) throws the "More data is available" error whenever `localStorage` is referenced.  Just by typing `localStorage` <Enter> in the console is enough to trigger it.  It seems like a bug in IE, or an unusual environment setting, for sure.

Comment: Just ran into this too and surprised not to find more information about the error.  Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a solid answer for this, but I've been debugging this error on a remote user's box for about a month.  I haven't had direct access to the box, but what I do know is:

1. in my particular case, any reference to `localStorage` caused the "SCRIPT234: More data is available" exception.  This is slightly different than the OP's problem
2. Error 234: More data is available is a [low-level Windows system error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ERROR_MORE_DATA)
3. It doesn't matter whether "Enable DOM Storage" is checked inside "Tools / Internet options / Advanced / Security / Enable DOM Storage", the error happens both ways
4. It happened in a very recent build of IE 11: IE 11.0.9600.17501
5. There is no record of this error ever happening inside IE except for this SO question.  It's typically a system-level error.  The fact that it's bubbled up into the JS console is troubling.  Usually when an OS reveals its guts to a webpage, the page can reach in and steal some organs.

[image: screenshot of error]

Ultimately, the error stopped appearing, but the actual fix is unknown to me.  The user did clear the browser cache (maybe it was corrupted?) just before it was resolved, but it could also have been a Windows update that resolved the problem, or some other unknown change.  At this point, I have no idea how to reproduce it, but hopefully some of the info above will help the next person who runs into it.

Answer (score 4):

One of our clients encountered this error and sent us a screenshot(IE9 Windows 7).
[image: SCRIPT234: More data is available error in Internet Explorer console log]

Our webpage was similarly making use of localStorage.

I can confirm that [clearing the cache](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=15141) fixed this problem

```
1. Select Tools (via the Gear Icon) > Safety > Delete browsing history...
NOTE: You can also access this menu by holding Ctrl + Shift + Delete.

2. Make sure to uncheck Preserve Favorites website data and check both Temporary Internet Files and Cookies then click Delete.
Uncheck Preserve Favorites website data; Check both Temporary Internet Files and Cookies; > Delete

3. You will get a confirmation at the bottom of the window once it has successfully cleared your cache and cookies.

Further Troubleshooting

1. Close out of Internet Options. Click on Tools and select Developer Tools.

2. In the Developer Tools window, click on Cache and select Clear Browser Cache...

3. Click Yes to confirm the clearing of the browser cache.
```

Comment: Please add some information to your answer from the link. That could become broken down the line, and your answer would no longer be as effective.